# TOC title formatting amsart

Tags: table-of-contents, amsart

I am using `amsart`. How can I change `\scshape` to `\bfseries` in contents (the title formatting of the TOC) below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newsectionstyle}{%
  \renewcommand{\@secnumfont}{\bfseries}
  \renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{2}%
    \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
    {\normalfont\bfseries}}%
}
\let\oldsection\section% Store original \section
\let\old@secnumfont\@secnumfont% Store original \@secnumfont
\newcommand{\originalsectionstyle}{%
  \let\@secnumfont\old@secnumfont
  \let\section\oldsection
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newsectionstyle

\section{Linear Operators}\lipsum[1-10]

\section{The Real Method}\lipsum[11-20]

\section{The Complex Method}\lipsum[21-30]

\subsection{Hadamard's Three Lines Lemma}\lipsum[31-40]

\section{Interpolation of Analytic Families of Operators}\lipsum[41-50]

\originalsectionstyle

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{abc} Abc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a compilable document, not just a screenshot

Comment: `\renewcommand{\contentsnamefont}{\bfseries}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`amsart` defines `\contentsnamefont` to be a wrapper for `\scshape`.

In this case, `\renewcommand{\contentsnamefont}{\bfseries}` is sufficient!

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newsectionstyle}{%
  \renewcommand{\@secnumfont}{\bfseries}
  \renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{2}%
    \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
   {\normalfont\bfseries}}%
}

\renewcommand{\contentsnamefont}{\bfseries}
\let\oldsection\section% Store original \section
\let\old@secnumfont\@secnumfont% Store original \@secnumfont
\newcommand{\originalsectionstyle}{%
  \let\@secnumfont\old@secnumfont
  \let\section\oldsection
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newsectionstyle

\section{Linear Operators}\lipsum[1-10]

\section{The Real Method}\lipsum[11-20]

\section{The Complex Method}\lipsum[21-30]

\subsection{Hadamard's Three Lines Lemma}\lipsum[31-40]

\section{Interpolation of Analytic Families of Operators}\lipsum[41-50]

\originalsectionstyle

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{abc} Abc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my point of view the indent of `subsection` in the ToC should be increased!

Comment: a number of "improvements" are on the wish list for the toc; what is wanting is for an overhaul of the ams document classes to be scheduled.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I don't understand what you mean -- I provided the solution the O.P. asked for

Comment: improving the format of the toc has been on the ams wish list for years.  however, although there are many known bugs in the document classes, overhaul of the `.cls` files never seems to get put on the work schedule.  (believe me, the improvement you suggest is on the list, and will be implemented ... when the work is finally undertaken.)